# Batch class start method returning null, even after a record has been inserted in the test class

Tags: unit-test, batch, code-coverage

I have a batch test class:

```
@isTest
public with sharing class TestBatchManagement {
    @isTest
    public static void batchManagementTest() {
        User u = TestDataFactory.createUserWithRoleLeader();
        
        Test.startTest();
        System.runAs(u) {
            List<Knowledge__kav> k = TestDataFactory.createKnowledgeExternalFAQ();
            
            Knowledge__kav kQuery = [
                SELECT id, createdByID, createdBy.UserRole.DeveloperName,LastModifiedBy.UserRole.DeveloperName,
                RecordType.DeveloperName
                FROM Knowledge__kav
                WHERE LastModifiedBy.UserRole.DeveloperName != 'Super' 
                AND ((LastModifiedBy.UserRole.DeveloperName= 'Leader' AND RecordType.DeveloperName != 'CC') OR LastModifiedBy.UserRole.DeveloperName != 'Leader')
                
            ];
        }
        BatchManagement bm = new BatchManagement();
        Database.executeBatch(bm);
        Test.stopTest();
    }
}
```

The problem is in the batch class the query locator returns no records. Even in the test class, if I do a query for Knowledge__kav, it returns `List has no rows for assignment to SObject` unless in the `WHERE` I add this `id =: k[0].id`.

Why is it so? And how can I solve this?

UPDATE:

doing `KbManagement.PublishingService.publishArticle(kQuery.KnowledgeArticleId, false);` in the test class did the trick. In the batch class, the start method returns the query and the inserted KAV's `PublishStatus` is `Online`.
But unfortunately in the batch class I have condition where the KAV's `PublishStatus` has to `Draft` or `Archived`. So now I can return the KAV I created in test class through the batch's start method but because of the condition the code coverage is insufficient.

Comment: How would a query in the test class return null? It should either return an exception or an empty list if no records are found. Assuming that is the actual behaviour, does the query return no records even if you completely omit the WHERE clause?

Comment: by null I meant "List has no rows for assignment to SObject"
yes if I omit the where clause it says "List has no rows for assignment to SObject".

Comment: Option 1: test the batch class start(), execute(), and finish() methods separately rather than using `Database.executeBatch()`; Option 2: Use dependency injection to the batch class's object to provide an alternate selector for the start() method

Answer (score 0):

It seems the problem is with the Apex API version. The API version was 46 when the project started. Changing it version 48.0 worked.